# Is there a way to dinamically translate javascript variables in Symfony?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have a twig variable with a value like:

```
{{ var | trans }}
```

Obviously this is working as intended in the HTML when the page loads, but I need to be able to change the variable's value with javaScript dinamically.

Now, I get that twig is executed on the server-side, but I was wondering if there is some workaround to get this translated using Symfony's translator (or other options).

**I have learned that you cannot pass variables from PHP to JS using an external file**, which I am using, but still, I am not sure if there is no option whatsoever to achieve what I need. Been searching for a while and I know there are more lookalike questions like this one but no answer responded to this specific question.

Comment: How do you find this questions so quickly? Yes! it solves it, thx!

Comment: My memory is still serving me well :3